# autosave checkboxes on click

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

I have my forms in a loop gerating many forms with checkboxes.The choices are submitted via a hidden iframe that runs my php.Can i make this checkboxes autosave to the database ?

```
<form action='http://www.toppromomkt.com/wp-content/themes/toppromo/insert_wallet.php' method='post'  class="my-form" target='hidden-form'>
  <input class="styled"  type='checkbox' name='pago'   value='yes' <?php if ($che=='yes') {echo "checked='yes'"; } else if ($cccc='') {} else {} ; ?> > <br> </div><div class='tb1 tb1_small sc' >
  <input class="styled"  type='checkbox' name='recibo'   value='yes' <?php if ($rec=='yes') {echo "checked='yes'";} else{}; ?>  > <br></div><div class='tb1 tb3_md sc '>
  <input class="styled"  type="hidden" name="contador"  readonly value="<?php  echo $id_postt1."linha_".$events[0];  ?>"> 
  <input class="styled"  type="hidden" name="id_p"  readonly value="<?php  echo $events[2];?>"> 
  <input type='Submit' class="button white small" value='Salvar' onclick='saved(<?php echo $fid ?>)' />
</form>
```

Comment: I think you can do this with AJAX.

Comment: You have to use AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `setInterval` which will be initialized on click of checkbox and will make an ajax request to save it to DB.

Following is a sample code:

#### Code

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/Lqhyn1oa/)

```js
var formCount = 1;
var saveInterval = null;
var data = []; // Used to mimic DB

function createForm() {
  var html = "<form id='frm_" + formCount + "' >"
  for (var i = 0; i < 5;) {
    html += "<input type='text' name='input_" + ++i + "' /> <br/>";
  }
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += html;
  formCount++;
}

function autoSaveInit(el) {
  if (el.checked) {
    if (!saveInterval) {
      saveInterval = setInterval(function() {
        saveData();
      }, 3000);
    }
  } else {
    window.clearInterval(saveInterval);
    saveInterval = null;
  }
}

function saveData() {
  var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
  var _tempObj = {};

  // Reset Data for Demo purpose.
  data = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    _tempObj = new Object();
    _tempObj.formID = forms[i].id;
    _tempObj.data = [];
    var inputs = forms[i].getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
      var name = inputs[j].name;
      _tempObj.data.push({
        "name": name,
        "value": inputs[j].value
      });
    }
    data.push(_tempObj);
  }
  console.log("Save Completed: ", data);
}
```

```html
Following is a sample for generating form with auto-save;
<div id="content"></div>
<button onclick="createForm()">Create Form</button>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkAutoSave" onclick="autoSaveInit(this)">
<label for="chkAutoSave">Auto save forms?</label>
```